# Double-click an NSImageCell subclass

Tags: cocoa

I have a table of draggable rows. I'm subclassing NSImageCell to render an image, mapped via bindings.

How do I get a double-click event from this cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd send a `setDoubleAction:` message to the NSTableView, and in your double-click action method, use `clickedRow` to find out which row was hit.

Comment: Yep it was the Action Invocation stuff on the Table View. 

I'd also forgotten all about binding to selector names.

Here's the article that helped me get it working. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2006/qa1472.html